# Looking for help trying to print class properties to console from two different classes but keeping them paired as when they were entered

Tags: c#, class, printing, properties, console

I am working on a "homework assignment" for a tutorial I was doing on instantiated classes. I am trying to figure out how to print to the console at the end the users first and last name, along with the address they entered. I have one public class that has the properties for first name and last name, and another public class with the properties for street address, city, state, zip code, then a third class to "handle" the output of the data to the console. What I would like to accomplish is enter in user data and when I'm done have it print to console like the following:

Name: Fred Durst
Address: 1234 Fake Street N. Fake City, FS 69696

Name: Bill Muri
Address: 4321 Fake Street S. Fake City, FS 69696

I only know how to get it to print all the names, then all the addresses. I did some searching on here but don't know enough to really understand the answers I'm reading and if they're applicable or not to my scenario.

Main Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleUI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstName = "";
            List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();
            List<AddressModel> address = new List<AddressModel>();

            do
            {
                Console.Write("What is your first name? (type exit to stop): ");
                firstName = Console.ReadLine();

                if (firstName.ToLower() != "exit")
                {
                    Console.Write("What is your last name?: ");
                    string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("What is your Street Address?: ");
                    string streetAddress = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("What is the city you live in?: ");
                    string city = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("What is the state you live in?: ");
                    string state = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("What is your zip code?: ");
                    string zipCode = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool isValid = int.TryParse(zipCode, out int outputZipCode);

                    PersonModel person = new PersonModel();
                    person.UserFirstName = firstName;
                    person.UserLastName = lastName;
                    people.Add(person);

                    AddressModel userAddress = new AddressModel();
                    userAddress.UserStreetAddress = streetAddress;
                    userAddress.UserCity = city;
                    userAddress.UserState = state;
                    userAddress.UserZipCode = outputZipCode;
                    address.Add(userAddress);

                }
            } while (firstName.ToLower() != "exit");


            foreach (PersonModel p in people)
            {
                ProcessPerson.GreetPerson(p);
            }
            foreach (AddressModel a in address)
            {
                ProcessPerson.SayUserAddress(a);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

AddressModel Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleUI
{
    public class AddressModel
    {
        public string UserStreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string UserCity { get; set; }
        public string UserState { get; set; }
        public int UserZipCode { get; set; }

        public bool HasBeenGreeted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PersonModel Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleUI
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
        public string UserLastName { get; set; }

        public bool HasBeenGreeted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProcessPerson Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleUI
{
    public static class ProcessPerson
    {
        public static void GreetPerson(PersonModel person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello { person.UserFirstName } { person.UserLastName }");
            //Console.WriteLine($"Your Address is: { userAddress.UserStreetAddress } { userAddress.UserCity } { userAddress.UserState } { userAddress.UserZipCode }");
            person.HasBeenGreeted = true;
        }

        public static void SayUserAddress(AddressModel userAddress)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your Address is: { userAddress.UserStreetAddress } { userAddress.UserCity } { userAddress.UserState } { userAddress.UserZipCode }");
            userAddress.HasBeenGreeted = true;
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to relate an address to a person. Right now you have no way of knowing a person's address once each loop iteration ends.

If there is one address per person then add a property to `PersonModel` of type `AddressModel`.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }    
    public bool HasBeenGreeted { get; set; }

    public AddressModel Address {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your code, set the property instead of adding addresses to a list:

```
AddressModel userAddress = new AddressModel();
userAddress.UserStreetAddress = streetAddress;
userAddress.UserCity = city;
userAddress.UserState = state;
userAddress.UserZipCode = outputZipCode;

//instead of this:
//address.Add(userAddress);

// do this:
person.Address = userAddress;
```

Then you can use `person.Address.<any property>` in the console output.

Comment: Thank you for your help!